# Drupal in docker - missing sites/default/modules/admin_menu/admin_devel/admin_devel.js

Tags: docker, module, drupal-7

I installed Drupal and it is now up and running: https://uat-a2v.910ths.sa/

The error message in the browser was:

> Notice :tempnam(): file created in the system's temporary directory في
>   drupal_tempnam() (السطر 2478 من /var/www/html/includes/file.inc).
>   Warning :file_put_contents(temporary://fileoelNJj): failed to open
>   stream: "DrupalTemporaryStreamWrapper::stream_open" call failed في
>   file_unmanaged_save_data() (السطر 1936 من
>   /var/www/html/includes/file.inc). لم يتم إنشاء الملف. Notice
>   :tempnam(): file created in the system's temporary directory في
>   drupal_tempnam() (السطر 2478 من /var/www/html/includes/file.inc).
>   Warning :file_put_contents(temporary://filelNgjCG): failed to open
>   stream: "DrupalTemporaryStreamWrapper::stream_open" call failed في
>   file_unmanaged_save_data() (السطر 1936 من
>   /var/www/html/includes/file.inc). لم يتم إنشاء الملف.

Nevertheless, the error message in the nginx is different :

```
docker logs --tail=0 --follow  docker_nginx_1
```

> 2018/07/01 09:37:47 [error] 20#20: *128968 open()
>   "/var/www/html/sites/default/modules/admin_menu/admin_devel/admin_devel.js"
>   failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 10.55.10.198, server:
>   drupal, request: "GET
>   /sites/default/modules/admin_menu/admin_devel/admin_devel.js?pb6kzx
>   HTTP/1.1", host: "uat-a2v.910ths.sa", referrer:
>   "https://uat-a2v.910ths.sa/ar"

I understand that there is a missing module, named `admin_menu`, I went back to the code and `sites/default/modules` does not exist.

I created the folder

```
docker exec -u 0 docker_nginx_1 mkdir sites/default/modules
docker exec -u 0 docker_nginx_1 chown www-data:www-data sites/default/modules
```

I search on `admin_menu` module and I didn't find it neither in the admin dashboard nor in the internet.

is it something related to modules or .haccess?
How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, first I have a question for you: Is this a multisite and that's why you put your contrib modules in this directory?: sites/default/modules/

And If that's true...Please download the last stable version of the admin_menu and place it into the sites/default/modules/ directory.

The 404 error, cames because you don't have the admin_devel module directory and it is enabled in the database. The admin_devel is a submenu of the admin_menu module.

[image: This is the admin_menu module directory]